# How to find similarity distance between user's preference vector and items description table (matrices that are not the same size) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a two different datasets:

`users's "taste" table`:

```
+-------+---------+--------+---------+---------+-----+--
|user_id|  Action |Adventure|Animation|Children|Drama|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----+--
|   100 |    0    |    1    |    2    |   1    |  0  |
|   101 |    1    |    4    |    0    |   3    |  0  |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-----+--
```

`movie's genre table`:

```
+--------+---------+---- ----+---------+---------+-----+--
|movie_id|  Action |Adventure|Animation| Children|Drama|
+--------+---------+---- ----+---------+---------+-----+--
|   1001 |    0    |    1    |    1    |    1    |  0  |
|   1001 |    0    |    1    |    0    |    1    |  0  |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+--
```

I am trying to recommend to user the most similar N movies based on his taste. What I thought is to measure the similarity distance (cosine similarity/dot product) between user and each movie and return top N most similar ones. What is the right way to implement it in python?

Answer (score 0):

It is a easy questions but depending on type of distance & size of data the answer can be complex. I give you some hooks to start with.

Sklearn has [distance metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) implemented, which you can use right away to calculate the distance between items, and for instance with help of argmax find the best match. This would be the naive approach, but works fine on small data sets and you have flexibility to use any metric you want.
Distances have the [pairwise](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.pairwise) implemented, made to easily calculate distance matrices to quickly find the best match. But you can imagine for larger data-sets this strategy wont work anymore.

When the data grows- you can use the [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) algorithm to quickly find the (1) k-nearest, or (2) all movies within certain threshold. This algorithm is well implemented in `sklearn`, and I would advise to start with this approach, as it is a good balance between fast and easy to implement.

Other option is to use specialised package like [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) or [ann](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emount/ANN/). Both would only use if above fails in terms of speed/size of data.